Trying to pass a Dictionary to a View
I am not able to figure out how can I fetch data from a ViewBag which contains a dictionary.
I am sharing the code below:
if (dataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count > 1) {
    evalMitModel = new EvaluationMitigationApproverModel();
    evalMitModel.MitigationType = new List<string>();
    evalMitModel.MitigationDescription = new List<string>();
    evalMitModel.PersonResponsible = new List<string>();
    evalMitModel.TargetDate = new List<string>();
    string temp = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[0]["id_hazard_trans"].ToString();
    int counter = 1;
    for (int index = 0; index < dataSet.Tables[2].Rows.Count; index++) {
        if (temp == dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["id_hazard_trans"].ToString()) {
            if (evalMitModel.HazardTransactionId == null) {
                evalMitModel.HazardTransactionId = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index] ["id_hazard_trans"].ToString();
                evalMitModel.HazardId = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["id_hazard"].ToString();
                evalMitModel.ImpactId = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["impact_id"].ToString();
                evalMitModel.LikeId = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["like_id"].ToString();
                evalMitModel.Scale = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["Scale"].ToString();
                evalMitModel.ApproverStatus = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]    ["apprv_status"].ToString();
                evalMitModel.ApproverComment = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["apprv_comment"].ToString();
            }
            evalMitModel.MitigationType.Add(dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["cnt_type"].ToString());
            evalMitModel.MitigationDescription.Add(dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["cnt_desc"].ToString());
            evalMitModel.PersonResponsible.Add(dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["pers_resp"].ToString());
        }
        else {

            evalMitHashMap.Add(counter++, evalMitModel);
            evalMitModel = new EvaluationMitigationApproverModel();
            evalMitModel.MitigationType = new List<string>();
            evalMitModel.MitigationDescription = new List<string>();
            evalMitModel.PersonResponsible = new List<string>();
            temp = dataSet.Tables[2].Rows[index]["id_hazard_trans"].ToString();
            index--;
            //evalMitModel.HazardTransactionId = null;
        }
    }
    evalMitHashMap.Add(counter, evalMitModel);
    ViewBag.EvaluationMitigationHashMap = evalMitHashMap;
}

I am trying to fetch the data using using the razor synatax in the view.
 @if (ViewBag.EvaluationMitigationHashMap != null) { foreach (var data in ViewBag.EvaluationMitigationHashMap) {

And? What happens when you do that?

I have solved the problem now, It was simple but didn't know why it didn't come to my mind while posting the question.
Fetched data: e.g  foreach(var data in ViewBag.EvaluationMitigationHashMap) {
@data.Value.
}
Dictionary:  Dictionary<int, EvaluationMitigationApproverModel> evalMitHashMap = new Dictionary<int, EvaluationMitigationApproverModel>();
